# Download Partial Video via HTTP (for Remote Thumbnailing)

Tags: video, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, thumbnails, h.264

I have videos hosted on Amazon S3.  I encode them with Zencoder and store a thumbnail for the video then using Zencoder.  However, I need a way to generate thumbnails at certain points in the video (i.e. 00:00:03, 00:10:32, 01:40:18) and store them either on S3 or my server.

ffmpeg allows remote thumbnailing, however it takes a very long time (sometimes several minutes) to get a thumbnail from the middle of a file--I believe this is because it downloads the entire file up to that point to get the thumbnail.

My plan is to somehow download the header of the video file via HTTP byte-range request, guesstimate the byte range where I should be looking for the thumbnail, download about a second of video from that part of the file via HTTP byte-range request, then save the header and tiny video locally.  I pull the thumbnail from that using ffmpeg and delete the temporary video.

I have no idea on how exactly this would work (I believe the H.264 MP4 files I'm working with have a dynamic length header, for another issue).  **Any suggestions or better ideas?**

**Edit**: To clarify, Zencoder thumbnailing is great, but they only allow thumbnail creation in combination with transcoding.  I don't want to transcode my video every time I create a new thumbnail, so I need to do this on my own without Zencoder.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

As expected, a quick search through the *Zencoder* [documentation](https://app.zencoder.com/docs) reveals similar functionality to be available there as well, please check their API reference for [Thumbnails](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails):

- [interval](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails/interval) - *Take thumbnails at an even interval, in seconds. Zencoder will return one thumbnail for every N seconds of the file. [...]*
- [interval_in_frames](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails/interval-in-frames) - *Take thumbnails at an even interval, in frames. Zencoder will return one thumbnail for every N frames of the file. [...]*
- [times](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails/times) - *An array of times, in seconds, at which to grab a thumbnail. Decimals are valid. So setting times to [12.5, 25] would grab two thumbnails, one at 12.5 seconds, and one at 25 seconds. [...]*

And (similar to *Transloadit*), *Zencoder* seems to support to *upload and download files from your Amazon S3 bucket* as well, see [Using Zencoder with S3](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/working-with-s3) for details.

Good luck!

---

Since you are using a cloud encoding service anyway, I'm going to take *"Any suggestions or better ideas?"* literally here and recommend to check out [*Transloadit*](http://transloadit.com/) eventually, insofar their offering includes your desired functionality (<strike>I'd actually expect this to be available from *Zencoder* as well</strike> *Zencoder* offers similar functionality indeed, see update above) - there are several [demos](http://transloadit.com/demos) for *Thumbnail extraction from videos*, e.g. [Extract 8 thumbnails from an encoded video](http://transloadit.com/demos/video-thumbs/extract-from-encoding):

> This is the simplest demo to extract thumbnails from a video encoding.
> By default it extracts 8 thumbnails at equal time intervals each
> having the same dimensions as the video. » [See full documentation](http://transloadit.com/docs/video-thumbs)

The `offset` parameter of the [/video/thumbs robot](http://transloadit.com/docs/video-thumbs) allows you to specify the thumbnail position more fine grained in either seconds of the file duration or respective percentage values instead.

*Transloadit* supports *Storing files in Amazon S3* as well, see e.g. the demo [Encode a video, extract 8 thumbnails and store everything in your S3 bucket](http://transloadit.com/demos/s3-store/store-encoding-and-thumbnails) for a combined solution addressing your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem with Zencoder thumbnails is that you can only generate one along with transcoding a video--you can't just generate a thumbnail alone later on.  I'll look at Transloadit but it's not really reasonable for us to switch services right now.  I'd really appreciate an answer that uses only scripts on my own server to handle this.